# 1D Diffusion With Opposing Dirichlet and Neumann Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying solve a single dimension diffusion problem, where

$\frac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 c(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$ over $0 \leq x\leq L$.

and $c(0,t)=c_0$, $\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}(L,t)=0$, and $c(x,0)=0$.

Using the Laplace transform of my relation,

I get the ODE $C(x,s)=\frac{D}{s}\frac{\partial^2 C(x,s)}{\partial x^2}$ with the following conditions:

$C(L,s)=0$ (I think that's right?)
and
$C(0,s)=\frac{c_0}{s}$

Accordingly, I think I've found the following as a potential solution in the Laplace domain, where I assume $c_0=1$:

$C(x,s)=\frac{\text{csch}\left(L \sqrt{\frac{s}{D}}\right) \sinh \left(\sqrt{\frac{s}{D}} (L-x)\right)}{s}$

Now my question is, how can this be applied with the inverse Laplace transform to find the solution in the time domain?

Ultimately, I'm looking for a solution that I can integrate with respect to x from 0 to L.  I've looked through Crank's book on "The Mathematics of Diffusion" but those solutions for "diffusion in a plane" are infinite sums Fourier series.

Comment: Why don't you want to have the inifinite Fourier series?

Comment: Good question.  Mainly I thought there should be a better answer, in that there's not a question of computation and accuracy.  If I'm going to use lots of computations, I might as well do it with numerical approximation.  That and I don't understand taking the integral of infinite series... though I suppose it's possible!  I'm researching "Green's Functions" currently, per reading another post.  Thanks.

Comment: The closed form turns out to be the antiderivative of a Jacobi $\vartheta$-function, which is probably not what you want. This being the heat equation, for $t>0$ the Fourier series converges exponentially anyway.

Comment: Well then I won't try that approach any further because such things are beyond my particular understanding for now.  Ultimately, I want to be able to be able to determine the total concentration ("mass") in the 1d relation at a time, t.  Was thinking it'd be something simple.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Once you use Laplace, you'll arrive to a series because the hyperbolic functions in the denominator has infinity poles. Then, it's better to start with Fourier anyway.

Comment: I see, thanks.  For the record, Crank has a solution with two infinite summations of Erfc() functions for "small time" (Eq. 4.19).  I get seemingly good results with 10 terms and couldn't get the "regular" Fourier solution (Eq 4.17)to work intelligibly to compare, though I suspect a syntax typo on my part.